# How do I professionally respond to job extension?

Tags: job-offer

I was alacrity to work in my existing company and they have offered extension to few more months. I wanted to say thanks, has it really help me to learn more about the technologies  and get to know you all people .

Comment: Don't make too much about it. As you already suggested just say "Thank you, that helps me to learn more about the technologies and get to know you all people".

Answer (score 4):

The only thing you have to do is either accept or reject the offer by the specified date. If you want to be complimentary, say exactly what you said. For example, "I accept the offer and look forward to working with you and learning more."